# Laravel one to many relationship doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, laravel

**This relationship of mine was working last week, but it stopped working.**

*When i use it in my blade template it says: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object.*

*The weird thing is, when i use it in dd() it perfectly shows, but when i try to print it in blade, it doesn't.*

Code PaymentsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Betaling;
use App\Settings;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PaymentsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $user_id = auth()->user('id');

        $role = auth()->user()->role_id;

        $settings = Settings::where('user_id', $user_id->id)->first();

        if ($role === 1){
            $totaalaantalbetalingen = Betaling::all();
        } else {

        $totaalaantalbetalingen = Betaling::where('user_id', $user_id->id)->get();
    }
        return view('payments.index', compact(['totaalaantalbetalingen','role', 'user_id', 'settings']));
    }
}
```

Code index.blade.php

```
@foreach($totaalaantalbetalingen as $betaling)
  <tr>
  <th scope="row">{{ $betaling->id }}</th>
  @if($role === 1)

  <td>{{ $betaling->user->name }} </td>
  @endif
  <td>{{ $betaling->customer->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $betaling->reference}}</td>
  <td>€ {{ $betaling->amount}}</td>
  <td>{{ $betaling->time_of_invoice }}</td>
  <td>{{ $betaling->time_of_payment }}</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>{{ $betaling->user->location }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

code User model:

```
public function betalingen(){
    return $this->hasMany(Betaling::class);
}
```

code Betaling model:

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

code Customer model:

```
public function betaling(){
    return $this->hasMany(Betaling::class);
}
```

Comment: On which line you are getting this error..

Comment: <td>{{ $betaling->user->name }} </td>

<td>{{ $betaling->customer->name }}</td>

<td>{{ $betaling->user->location }}</td>

All 3 of these lines

Comment: You are calling it wrong "user->name" the problem is in here i didnot know the Syntax but its definitely not calls like this let me google the syntax

Comment: Can you show how you have assigned `$totaalaantalbetalingen` in your controller?

Comment: I edited my controller content in, check original message

Comment: Found the problem, i used a factory to seed my controllers, tried commenting it out and it works again.

Answer (score 1):

pass  `auth()->user()->id` and in blade file check `!empty($totaalaantalbetalingen)`

**code User model:**

```
public function betalingen(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Betaling','betalingenid','id'); // pass foreign key for ex.
}
```

**code Betaling model:**

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','customer_id','id');// pass foreign key for ex.
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');// pass foreign key for ex.
}
```

**code Customer model:**

```
public function betaling(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Betaling','customer_id','id');// pass foreign key for ex.
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function index(){

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $role = auth()->user()->role_id;

        $settings = Settings::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();

        if ($role == 1){
            $totaalaantalbetalingen = Betaling::all();
        } else {

        $totaalaantalbetalingen = Betaling::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    }
        return view('payments.index', compact(['totaalaantalbetalingen','role', 'user_id', 'settings']));
    }
```

**blade.php**

```
@if(!empty($totaalaantalbetalingen) && isset($totaalaantalbetalingen))
@foreach($totaalaantalbetalingen as $betaling)
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $betaling->id ?? '' }}</th>
      @if($role === 1)

      <td> {{ $betaling->user->name ?? '' }} </td>
      @endif
      <td> {{ $betaling->customer->name ?? '' }} </td>
      <td> {{ $betaling->reference ?? '' }} </td>
      <td> € {{ $betaling->amount ?? '' }} </td>
      <td> {{ $betaling->time_of_invoice ?? '' }} </td>
      <td> {{ $betaling->time_of_payment  ?? '' }} </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> {{ $betaling->user->location ?? '' }} </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Please mark as verified this answer if its help for you Thank you @Roel Sax